# How to extract the value of a regex backreference?

Tags: .net, html, regex, vb.net

So I  have been using regular expressions for years, mostly in a PHP environment, but I am working on a small project which uses the VB .NET scripting engine (I have VB experience, but that's it), and am having some real problems doing something really basic.

I have a variable which has the content of an HTML file loaded, and I want to extract the value of a certain tag.

Example:

```
<span id="temp" class="up"><span class="up">76.4</span></span>
```

After studying up on the changes for .NET based regular expressions, this is what I came up with (with backreference 1 allowing me to capture that number):

```
<span id="temp" class="(?:up|down)"><span class="(?:|up|down)">([0-9]+\.[0-9]{1})</span>
```

However, I can not get this to work.  The RegEx Hero site seems to validate the regular expression, so I am guessing the problem is with my code.  I have followed many examples on the net, but always run into some sort of error.  Even worse, I am developing this script using notepad :p

Can someone please provide me with a working VB .NET scripting example which extracts that number?  The goal is to replace all the text in that HTML variable with just the number.

Comment: Your regex is fine so you're probably right that it's your code. Post what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression is seems to be valid. The only thing I'd add is a named group for number. Try this:

```
Dim input = "<span id=""temp"" class=""up""><span class=""up"">76.4</span></span>"
Dim regex = New Regex("<span id=""temp"" class=""(?:up|down)""><span class=""(?:|up|down)"">(?<number>[0-9]+\.[0-9]{1})</span>")
Dim number = regex.Match(input).Groups("number").Value
```

it should get you `76.4`.

And one more thing - when parsing HTML it's just always better [to use HTML parser instead of regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/102112). I'd suggest [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Thanks, the problem was my code, guess I looked at too many examples, and ended up with Frankenstein code.  Your example was simple, and helped explain how to access this data.  I would vote you up, but don't have enough rep yet.